# CS1501; No overload for method x takes 0 arguments

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio-2022

Form1.cs Line 41, Suppression State Active

Line 41: BitlockerDataViewer.ShowBalloonTip();

The label BitlockerDataViewer is a notification thing don’t know what it’s called but it shows a balloon tip.

To get the app to start and show the balloon tip as expected.

---

I got the program to show the icon, but I want it to show the balloon tip as well.

Comment: The method requires a parameter. Doesn't intellisense tell you what it expects?

Comment: Did, but it either gives another error or gives me the wrong code. All I want is to span a balloon notification in the taskbar. This thing is confusing and I'm like a dummy. If I have to get around that then I will just create a message box instead.